# Can't get meta option to output anything for HTML Webpack Plugin

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Docs make it sound like I can output my header meta with the following:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    title: 'Benjamin Chirlin - Web Devloper',
    filename: "./index.html",
    meta: {
      description: "A description",
      author: "My Name" ,
      viewport: "width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1"
    }
  })
]
```

Removing my template option helped make the `title` option work but no matter what I try meta seems broken still. I found more detailed examples in [the spec](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/spec/BasicSpec.js) but even following those it doesn't work...help please? Guessing I have something wrong in my config somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta doesn't currently have an output in the default webpack template. I ended up using the extended [HTML Webpack Template plugin](https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template) which requires a slightly different format but *does* work out of the box. It's silly webpack would provide options that have no default output. You can theoretically write your own template that would loop through all the options etc but that's a major pain (considering it's a built in option).

Comment: Oh my god, thank you, I was bashing my head against the table. Why not mention it in the docs?

Comment: No one ever gives docs the love they deserve :( Me included